# Как на чистом js или на jquery сделать прелоадер для картинок?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как на чистом js или на jquery сделать прелоадер для картинок?
Причем просто задав URL, а не поиск по DOM $('#a img')?

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем ясна формулировка Вашего вопроса, в частности его вторая часть. 
Самый простой вариант прелоадера картинок:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    //картинка загрузилась
};
img.src = 'путь к файлу';
```

Вообще рекомендую посмотреть на [YepNope](http://yepnopejs.com/), очень мощный прелоадер файлов:

```
yepnope({
    load: 'preload!test.jpg', 
    callback : function (url, result, key) {
        //картинка загрузилась
    }
});
//Префикс preload нужен для того, чтобы не было попыток выполнить загруженный файл
```